# How to run maven project using batch file?

Tags: java, eclipse, batch-file

This is what i have done till now:

1. I have API automation Script in maven using testng, Following is the structure of project
   [image]

2.Now i first tried to run testng.xml using command-line with following command.

```
java -cp ".;C:\Users\A622965\.m2\repository\org\testng\testng\6.8\testng-6.8.jar" org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
```

3.But throws following error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.testng.TestNG
```

Not able to figure out the issue after watching lot of tutorials.
I am looking to batch process the script using Task Schedular in Windows

Comment: It seems my project is looks as your screenshot, In myproject there is no lib or bin folder. How did you manage this to call class path ? It would be great help so far.

Comment: will you please share your bat file syntax ? I do have Maven + TestNG framwork. Also not having lib and bin folder.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that Maven *is* a build tool, so every single operation which requires the classpath **must be done through Maven**, wether if you want to execute it from the command line or from some GUI.

So, in your case you will find useful the Maven command line tool:

```
mvn <phases>
```

In your case:

```
mvn test
```

But remember to include first in the `pom.xml` the `testng` library dependency, and also to properly configure the [surefire plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/testng.html).

Comment: Thank you very much. It cleared the concept for me. I have used the command (mvn clean test -DsuiteXmlFile=testng.xml) which i found on google. It works fine when i run by double clicking .bat file ,but when i schedule it using Task Scheduler it throws Build Failure. Why is this soo?

Comment: Yes Its working fine now! Actually i forgot to move to project directory first.

Answer (score 0):

**You need to build path for testng**

Right click-->Build -->Libraries Tab-->Add External jar-->Then restart--it will work...